# Перевод строки в байты в little endian и обратно в строку

Tags: python-3.x, строки, hex, конвертация

привет
есть строка в hex 'abcdef'
нужно перевернуть ее по 2 символа(bytes in little endian) в вид 'efcdab'

```
my_string = 'abcdef'
add_string = bytes.fromhex(my_string)
new_string = add_string[::-1].hex()
print(new_string, '\n', my_string, sep='')

'efcdab'
'abcdef'
```

тогда как для типа int есть более простой способ:

```
t = 12345678
new_t = (t.to_bytes(4, 'little')).hex()
print(new_t, '\n', t, sep='')
'4e61bc00' #нужен именно hex
'12345678'
```

Собственно вопрос в том, что есть ли способ для строки лучше чем я нашел? в одну строку, без дополнительных переменных, или хотя бы более производительный?

Заранее благодарен

Comment: Для 3 байт мне кажется вообще нет понятия "big endian" или "little endian", это больше характерно для представления типов данных с размером равным степени 2. Для 3 байт - это просто реверс байт. В принципе оба варианта вполне нормальные. Выводить кстати можно так: `print(new_t, t, sep='\n')`. Более производительно - если исходные данные не hex строка, а просто байты, то читать байты, разворачивать и выводить в байты, т.е. если возможно, то лучше убрать конверсию между машинным и человекочитаемым вариантами. Если нужно выводить на экран - то у вас вывод на экран будет занимать больше времени.

Comment: вывод на экран для примера, что получаем на выходе;       на входе есть строка, с ней делаем побайтные перестановки и обратно нужно получить опять строку;       3 байта это для примера, моя строка 32 байта.